# Reconnect minion on a new salt-master causes issues

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to reconnect minions to my new salt-master. 
To do that,

- I changed the sources.list

  - installing the new version of salt-minion (from 2015 to 2017.7.8)
  - Disconnect the minion from the old salt-master (I had two master to manage the old server because the internal application wasn't
    uptodate to run a 2017 version of salt, and one for the uptodate
    infrastructure)
  - I ran `rm -r /etc/salt/pki`
  - `systemctl force-reload salt-minion.servce`
  - I accepted the key on my new master
  - I ran `salt-call state.sls motd` (or whatever the formula)

The point is the following. For few of my minions, I cannot say why, but when I ran the last command `salt-call state.sls motd` I get this issue:

```
[ERROR   ] An un-handled exception was caught by salt's global exception handler:
KeyError: 'saltutil.is_running'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/salt-call", line 11, in <module>
    salt_call()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/scripts.py", line 396, in salt_call
    client.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/cli/call.py", line 58, in run
    caller.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/cli/caller.py", line 134, in run
    ret = self.call()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/cli/caller.py", line 204, in call
    ret['return'] = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/state.py", line 1071, in sls
    conflict = running(concurrent)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/state.py", line 209, in running
    active = __salt__['saltutil.is_running']('state.*')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 1121, in __getitem__
    func = super(LazyLoader, self).__getitem__(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/lazy.py", line 101, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'saltutil.is_running'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/salt-call", line 11, in <module>
    salt_call()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/scripts.py", line 396, in salt_call
    client.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/cli/call.py", line 58, in run
    caller.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/cli/caller.py", line 134, in run
    ret = self.call()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/cli/caller.py", line 204, in call
    ret['return'] = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/state.py", line 1071, in sls
    conflict = running(concurrent)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/modules/state.py", line 209, in running
    active = __salt__['saltutil.is_running']('state.*')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/loader.py", line 1121, in __getitem__
    func = super(LazyLoader, self).__getitem__(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/utils/lazy.py", line 101, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'saltutil.is_running'
```

My salt version:

```
Salt Version:
           Salt: 2017.7.8

Dependency Versions:
           cffi: 0.8.6
       cherrypy: Not Installed
       dateutil: 2.2
      docker-py: Not Installed
          gitdb: Not Installed
      gitpython: Not Installed
          ioflo: Not Installed
         Jinja2: 2.7.3
        libgit2: Not Installed
        libnacl: Not Installed
       M2Crypto: 0.21.1
           Mako: Not Installed
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.4.2
   mysql-python: 1.2.3
      pycparser: 2.10
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
   pycryptodome: Not Installed
         pygit2: Not Installed
         Python: 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31)
   python-gnupg: Not Installed
         PyYAML: 3.11
          PyZMQ: 14.4.0
           RAET: Not Installed
          smmap: Not Installed
        timelib: Not Installed
        Tornado: 4.2.1
            ZMQ: 4.0.5

System Versions:
           dist: debian 8.8
         locale: UTF-8
        machine: x86_64
        release: 3.16.0-4-amd64
         system: Linux
        version: debian 8.8
```

I tried to uninstall salt-minion with:

```
apt-get autoremove salt-minion* -y
apt-get purge salt-minion* -y
aptitude purge salt-minion -y
```

And `apt-get update & install salt-minion`
But I still have the exact same error. And not on every minions. For some of them, I have the exact same configuration on each server, and it can work for one and not the other.

Any clue? Help :s

Comment: I found the solution !
Actually if you encounter this error, you just have to run this command:
`apt install python-concurrent.futures`